# Google Position Ranking for Specisific Keyword and Domain

Tags: search-engines, google-search

How i can now my website position ranking for specific keywords?

example my website is `gusdecool.com` and i want to know my position ranking on Google search for keyword `Rapidleech`

How to do that? or maybe google has service to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register for [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools).  If the search term is relevant for your site, it will be displayed in a table including its position in the search results.

Comment: The webmaster tools' Search Query tab gives the same results I've suggested in the previous answer :)

Comment: @Aznim But you are missing the causality: The positions and keywords are primarily generated in the webmaster tools.  Analytics only gives you the possibility to display them there, AFTER you have enabled webmaster tools and linked them to the analytics account.

Comment: Forgot about that one, sorry... In either case it doesn't hurt to use both services in tandem.

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics provides a tool for this in Traffic sources / SEO / Queries...
This doesn't exactly show you the keywords, only the queries by which your site was found by the visitors or would be clients.